# Proper Way to Integrate Complex Number expression?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

I'm struggling to understand what the proper way to integrate complex number expressions is.

I understand that for a simple expression like $\int (x + xi) dx$, we treat *i* as a constant, as it doesn't change. Therefore we get $\int (x) dx + i\int (x) dx$.

However, what about an expression such as $\int sin(x + xi) dx$? Would the next step of $\int sin(x) dx + \int sin(xi) dx$ be appropriate?

Or what about an expression such as $\int (2^{x + xi}) dx$?

Is there a separate set of rules that covers integration of complex numbers?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: In general, for *any* function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$, you define $\int_a^b f(x)~\mathrm{d}x:=\int_a^b \operatorname{Re}(f(x))~\mathrm{d}x+i\int_a^b\operatorname{Im}(f(x))~\mathrm{d}x$ (if the integrals exist). This is just the definition

Comment: For $\sin(x+xi)$, expand using the addition theorems for sine.  You get $\sin(x)\cosh(x) + i \cos(x)\sinh(x)$.  Integrate that.

Comment: Okay, is that addition theorem for sine a separate rule for imaginary numbers only, or is that also applicable to non-complex numbers? I'm just trying to figure out whether there is a whole different set of rules that complex numbers go by when talking about trig identities, integrals and stuff like that.